# Prevent HTML auto resizing?

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble keeping my html from auto-sizing. I used this code:

My codepen --> https://codepen.io/Mike-was-here123/full/oGWxam/

`<body style="min-width: 1920px; margin: 0 auto; max-height: 1080px;">`

This works to prevent resizing, but the main part/ box (`.parent`) resizes between `990 x 974px` and `585 x 974px` (my total is `1920 x 974px`). Plus my image tries to auto resize too no matter what my width or height is. Is their anyway i can just make it so it never resizes my html based on screen-size besides using `@media`?

I also tried putting that code in a `div`, but got the same outcome.

Comment: So you're looking for this to NOT be responsive? I'm confused what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: You're using the bootstrap container class, which is responsive and will resize based on the width. I would recommend either creating a custom container class (with a different name) or remove the bootstrap containers.

Comment: That works, thanks :D! Anyways to prevent image from resizing?

Comment: So anyway to prevent a image for resizing?

Comment: Are you using bootstrap classes? If yes then remove it.And what is the width of your image? If you dont want to make it auto resize then make sure your width is not set to "100%" and use px instead.

Comment: Nope still does it, here my codepen now --> https://codepen.io/Mike-was-here123/full/oGWxam/